# Find, Highlight, and Count a word list (or string) in MS Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to write a macro which will find text based on a checklist (you will see it in the code named checklist) in the current active document.  I have pasted snippets of code together to make the macro found below.  My problem lies in counting.  I am trying to find out how many times the macro highlights something.  Later this count will be used in conjunction with categories to count the amount of highlighted objects in a certain category (hopefully!).  I have to admit, I can only vaguely follow what this code is actually doing as I am new to VBA.  Any help would be much appreciated. All of my attempts to get an accurate count have failed.

To add to this, does anyone know of a method of counting for multiple lists? Say, I have a few words Apple and orange which belong to the fruit list and celery and broccoli which belong to the vege list.  Each time Apple (or orange) is used it adds one to the count for fruit.  The same goes for vegetables.  I then want to have this data exported to an excel sheet.  I know it sounds complicated.  I am sorry.  Thanks again for any help.

```
Sub CompareWordList()

'This macro will find all of the words or phrases in the checklist document (to be developed) and highlight them.
'Further to this, the macro will provide a word count which is to be added to certain assessment criteria
'which will be provided by ___ once the development of this macro is complete.

Dim sCheckDoc As String
Dim docRef As Document
Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim wrdRef As Object
Dim count As Integer

sCheckDoc = "C:\Users\Nathaniel\Documents\checklist.docx"
Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
Set Range = ActiveDocument.Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

docCurrent.Activate
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

count = 0

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    '.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = False

' I TRIED HERE* count = count +1
End With


    For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .MatchCase = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End With

    End If
     'and here *count = count + 1
Next wrdRef

count = count + 1


 If count <> 0 Then

    MsgBox _
    count & " item(s) highlighted "

    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing was not found in the document/selection matching the checklist"
End If


docRef.Close
docCurrent.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, Word does not offer a possibility in VBA to determine the number of replacements (in your case: the number of highlights). So, there is a workaround way suggested [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/GetNoOfReplacements.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the number of possible replacements using RegEx. Assign the entire content of your document to a string, and then count the number of RegEx matches. Something like this would work

```
Sub CountReplacements() ' Make sure you add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = "[0-9]" ' Change RegEx pattern to whatever works for you
    rex.Global = True
    Dim str As String: str = ActiveDocument.Content
    Debug.Print Rex.Execute(str).Count
End Sub
```